# Using Sendgrid with node.js attachments are empty / broken

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

Although I have verified that the file does exist and is accessible, the email that is sent attaches an empty file. I have tried 3 different ways to attach the file, all that return success from the send json response. The code I'm currently using is as follows. The rk object is simply a namespace.

```
console.log(call.recording);
var email = new rk.sendgrid.Email({
  to: '4namlet@gmail.com',
  from: rk.config.email_address,
  subject: 'RoadKid Feedback',
  text: 'Someone left feedback on your driver.'//,
  //files: [
  //  {
  //    contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
  //    url: call.recording
  //  }
  //]
});

email.addFile({
  filename: 'feedback.mp3',
  contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
  url: call.recording
});

rk.sendgrid.send(email, function(err, json) {
  if (err) { return console.error(err); }
  console.log(json);
});
```

An example url value is:

```
http://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC4a36110ce12a9cd68a947c87a3a6ab36/Recordings/RE568ecf17e4960105cd131507d49e182f.mp3
```

Comment: Also filed as a Github Issue, follow up will probably happen there first. https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/116

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Sendgrid was working fine. (thanks guys for the quick response!) It was a scoping issue. For some reason call.recording was getting clobbered or called weird or something. After the console log I added a:

`var recording_url = call.recording;`

and theeen...

`url: recording_url`

And it all worked. :-/